# Latex Replication of this Vim CheatSheet?

Tags: article, beamerarticle

Apologies if this question is not allowed on this StackExchange website. I would like to achieve the style shown in this [pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E15131/f17/topics/vim/vim-cheatsheet.pdf). I outline the essential features I would like to implement in my own document:

1. Title on top of the document (with Name + Email).
2. Two columns.
3. Similar page size and margins.

Comment: For the page geometry setup: `\usepackage{geometry}` (take a look at its manual to get the correct options, `margin=1cm` or something should do). And use the options `twocolumn` and `landscape` in the `\documentclass` options. You could manually place the title on the first page using explicit markup (for a one-shot document this should be ok, or do you want to create a documentclass/style from this?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be similar enough:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Title}
\newcommand{\subtitle}{Subtitle}
\author{Your Name (\href{mailto:your@email.com}{your@email.com})}
\date{December 2021}

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
    {\color{RawSienna}%
        {\large \bfseries \sffamily \@title \hfill \@date }\\
        \hrule%
        \vspace*{.5em}%
        {\large\subtitle\hfill\@author}\\%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\maketitle

\bigskip
\begin{multicols}{2}

\section*{Introduction}

\begin{tabular}[h]{@{}ll}
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\end{tabular}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\end{tabular}


\section*{Discussion}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\end{tabular}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\texttt{h} & Move left \\
\texttt{j} & Move down \\
\end{tabular}

\blindtext[10]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]